# simple angularjs injecting service data into controller

Tags: angularjs

Attempting to learn angularjs just because but not getting the basics.
Why doesn't this work? 'hello' is bound and will display "working" if uncommented.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('formService', function () {
     this.names = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];
}).controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, formService) {
    $scope.hello = formService.names[1];//"working";
}]);
```

[html fragment]

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FormCtrl">
{{hello}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've left of the string version of your service off.  So change:

```
.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, formService)
```

to

```
.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope','formService', function ($scope, formService)
```

Or because this is such a common, easy mistake to make some people use [`ngMin`](https://github.com/btford/ngmin).

Then you can use the form:  `.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, formService)` and let `ngMin` (for example in your build script) handle converting it to the min-safe form you used.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the formservice parameter in your controller function, you should see an error in the console. Everything else looks right.